# How can we align different line with different alignement in FomattedText 

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, formatted-text

I have to draw formatted text in such a manner that last line should always come with right align. for example.

"Some text ............................................................"
                                                            Right align.

I can set font size etc in formatted can i set text like it always come in next line with right align.

Comment: what control are you using to display your text? more information, please.

Comment: I have made my own use control for display the formatted text, and i m drawing it OnRender method of the control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TextBlock within the control to display the text, then simply set the Width to the width of the parent control and the TextAlignment property.

Comment: In TextBlock whole text would go to left or right but as i mentioned i mentioned that i want only last always come at right regardless how my remaining text alignment

Comment: Your last line would need to be in its own TextBlock, unfortunately. You can do this programmatically by deducing the last line, removing it from the initial TextBlock, and creating a new one and adding it to the end of the your control.